# Mixing up monadic functions with pure functions in do notation

Tags: haskell, coding-style, do-notation

I'm having trouble mixing up pure and monadic functions inside of do notation. I've got the feeling I am missing something obvious.

For example, say I got these functions

```
fa :: a -> IO b
fb :: b -> c
fc :: c -> IO d

z :: a -> IO c
z a = do x <- fa a
         y <- fb x
         z <- fc y
         return z
```

This doesn't work because of the

```
y <- fb x
```

line in z, but what is an elegant way of combining the pure fb function, with the monadic fa and fc functions?

Comment: What's wrong with `let y = fb x`?

Comment: Parens around a single variable are always superfluous, in `return (z)` as well as they would be in `fa a`. It is generally considered good style in Haskell to only use parentheses when they are necessary (unless of course [you're an MIT sophomore](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html))!

Comment: @leftaroundabout right you are!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the smallest change you can make and have it still work is this:

```
z a = do x <- fa a
         let y = fb x
         z <- fc y
         return z
```

There are a number of things you can do in this specific case that may not work in the more general case. You can "inline" the call to `fb`; eliminate the bind/return pair; and use monadic composition instead of do-notation. Putting all three of these into practice would yield

```
z = fa >=> fc . fb
```

although you can pick just the transformations that seem reasonable/readable/aesthetically pleasing for your specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the options, how would you personally decide how to write it?

Answer (score 3):

I'd write this particular example thus:

```
z a = do x <- fa a
         fc $ fb x
```

or

```
z a = fa a >>= fc . fb
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `let` for non-monadic bindings:

```
z :: a -> IO c
z a = do x <- fa a
         let y = fb x
         z <- fc y
         return (z)
```